# Grey instrumental test omitted when all testes started

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

I've occurred an annoying problem, one of the instrumental tests class is displayed on grey and when I start all tests (package androidTest) this one gets omitted (others start just fine). Any ideas what can be a reason of it?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class, true, false);

private MockWebServer server;

private LoginActivity loginActivity;

private SharedPreferences loginDetails;

public LoginActivityTest() {
    super(LoginActivity.class);
}

Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor giftListActivityMonitor;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    // Create a MockWebServer. These are lean enough that you can create a new
    // instance for every unit test.
    server = new MockWebServer();
    // Start the server.
    server.start();

    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());


    loginDetails = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getSharedPreferences("login_details",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginDetails.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    KupMiConstans.BASE_URL = server.url("/").toString();

    loginActivity = this.getActivity();

    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();

    giftListActivityMonitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(GiftListActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    new PrepareSingletons(getInstrumentation().getContext());
}

@Test
...

@Test
...


@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    SharedPreferences loginDetails = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getSharedPreferences("login_details",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginDetails.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    try {
        server.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: Test displayed on grey]

Answer (score 0):

That was stupid.

Grey icon was displayed because first thing in class HAVE TO BE default constructor. And class was omitted in tests before first test was based completely on espresso and it needed at least one assert*. It's weird that order is so important...